# Is "This brought me an idea" correct English?

Tags: idioms

Coming from German I wonder what the correct idiom is here.

> This brought me an idea.

or

> This made me an idea.

or

> This got me an idea.

or

> This gave me an idea.

Well, I guess I could say

> This made me think of an idea.

but I wonder what else is possible here.

What would you propose?

Comment: You never say - 'this made me idea', unless you, yourself, become an *idea*. :)

Comment: Okay ;) But are the other ones valid? Which one is the most usual?

Comment: depends on the context... 'this gave me an idea' or 'this made me think of an idea' in general cases.

Comment: @Cabbie407 Stick with "gave" for past-tense and "gives" for present-tense, as mentioned in the answer. The rest would ultimately be understandable and valid, but would sound very unusual.

Comment: Another idiom you might be interested in is "Then the idea *came to me*"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"This gave me an idea" is what you're looking for. The others don't quite work, except for the final (slightly awkward sounding) non-idiomatic option at the bottom.

Comment: Probably the most common form, depending on context, would be "That gives me an idea."

Comment: Or even "This gives me an idea" or "That gave me an idea"... I wouldn't say either is more common except that we may more commonly speak in one tense or another...

Answer (score 10):

If you were going to use brought (which would make sense if the *this* you're referring to didn't immediately give you the idea, but rather led you through a series of logical steps that resulted in the idea) it would not be uncommon to say "This brought me to *the idea of ______*" or more commonly "This brought me to _____". This phrase is especially useful when documenting a series of similar events and you don't want to use the same phrase over and over again.

Comment: You could also say "this led me to consider..." or "this led me to think of..."

Answer (score 1):

"This/that gave/gives me an idea" is definitely a good way to go.

Your last example is similar to another common way to say this, which doesn't involved the word 'idea':

> That made me think of something.

Which is what I commonly say.

Anything you think of is an idea, so it's not required that you use that word.

Answer (score 0):

imagine that 'This' is someone's name (for instance 'This Johnson'), and an 'Idea' is a brand name for something physical (for example a chair). Then it would be correct to say 'This brought me an Idea'. Otherwise you should be using 'This gave me an idea'